# C # Convert.ToDateTime() problem

Tags: c#-2.0

I read date string from the text file. 
eg. string date="12/02/2010 13:23:00 AM" (read from the text file).
Then, I just try to convert it to date using DateTime dt= Convert.ToDateTime(date);
If I run in Visual Studio, it's ok. But after installing this setup and If i run the exe, the date time format exception pop up. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the date read 2010/12/02?

Comment: Isn't it depends on how i set the date format in regional settings?

Answer (score 1):

`13:23:00 AM` is not a valid time.  It is essentially saying "1:23:00 PM AM".

Comment: under regions settings , If i change the time format to HH:mm:ss tt , i can see as i mentioned. And actually, this is what user set the datetime format to his pcs. not possible to tell them to change date format of around 40 pcs. they won't do it. any work around?

Comment: @David - On Windows 7, I only see options for `h:mm:ss tt`, `hh:mm:ss tt`, `H:mm:ss` and `HH:mm:ss`.  I do not see an option for `HH:mm:ss tt`.  The casing of `hh` vs. `HH` is important.  Lower-case `hh` returns a two digit, 12-hour hour,  and upper case `HH` returns a two digit, 24-hour hour.

Comment: yeah, but it's not the defualt time from the drop down list, they key in the time. you can key in HH:mm:ss tt to Time format box and your pc time change to sth like 23:21 PM.

Comment: maybe that's the reason I got the problem, Instead of choosing the defualt time , they just key in HH:mm:ss tt. But for such cases ,Is there any way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, if they enter an invalid format, things will not necessarily work correctly.  They need to drop the `tt` from the format, or else make the `HH` lowercase (`hh`).

Comment: Finally, I just write the function to change the datetime for such cases.might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hey The Input string is wrong. It should be `2/02/2010 13:23:00 PM` and not `2/02/2010 13:23:00 AM`

```
DateTime dt= Convert.ToDateTime("2/02/2010 13:23:00 PM");
```

- AM - 00 to 12 hrs
- PM - 13 to 24 hrs